# How to list Azure recovery services vault of all the subscription and export to csv with required parameter

Tags: azure, powershell, for-loop, scripting, azure-powershell

I have written a PowerShell script to retrieve list of Azure recovery service vaults across multiple subscription.

This is my code:

```
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

ForEach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions) {
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 77a74465-c065-4108-b270-edd84f918fe0

    $vaults = get-azrecoveryservicesvault
    
    ForEach ($vault in $vaults) 
    {
        Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $vault
        Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault |Select-Object "Name","ResourceGroupName","Location","SubscritptionId" | Export-Csv "C:\RSV-Report.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII -Append  
    }
}
```

This returns an output like this:

[image]

It is not returning the Subscription IDs for all the resources.

But, when I am calling single subscription and single resource group with this code:

```
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 77a74465-c065-4108-b270-********
Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault | Select-Object "Name","ResourceGroupName","Location","SubscriptionId" | Export-Csv "C:\report1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I get a perfect output:

[image]

I want the output to look the same as for a single subscription and single resource group for all at once.

I need help for output like above and I also want get subscription Name column.
I tried to pass subscription name in select-object in above codes but it gives blank entry in rows for subscription name column.

I want to thank in advance if anyone could help me.

I am new to powershell, I keep trying to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same SubscriptionId in each iteration hardcoded, where you should use the `Id` property from each $Subscription object you received with the `Get-AzSubscription` call.

Try

```
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# loop through the subscriptions and collect the output in variable $result
$result = foreach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions) {
    $null   = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $Subscription.Id
    $vaults = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault

    foreach ($vault in $vaults) {
        Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $vault
        # output a PSObject with the chosen properties
        Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault | Select-Object "Name","ResourceGroupName","Location","SubscriptionId" 
    }
} 

$result | Export-Csv "C:\RSV-Report.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: I tried but  above script is giving same output as I uploaded screenshot without subscription ID. Thanks for Commenting

Comment: @vishalsingh please try again. There was a typo: `SubscritptionId` --> `SubscriptionId`

Comment: Yes it worked, Thanks for help, How I can get subscription Name coloum ? I tried to add in select-object it gives black coloumn,

Comment: @vishalsingh You can add a new [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) to the list of properties in the `Select-Object` line: `@{Name = 'SubscriptionName'; Expression = {$($Subscription.Name)}}`

Comment: @vishalsingh Great! Please don't forget to mark this question "done" by accepting it.